# How to maximize/enlarge the navigation menu of Spyder with Anaconda?

Tags: spyder, anaconda3

I just downloaded Anaconda and I realized that the navigation menu has really small buttons.

Can someone help me make these buttons bigger please? This is an image of what the navigation menu looks like:

[image: My Navigation Menu in Spyder]